# How to see default NVENC hevc options in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, nvenc

I am trying to use the hevc_nvenc encoder in ffmpeg to reencode an old video I have. Obviously software encoding using libx265 would be better, but I want to make in fast. I am trying to optimize for video quality, so I am using these options:

```
-profile:v main -b_ref_mode 0 -preset p7 -tune hq -rc vbr
```

`b_ref_mode 0` since my gpu doesn't support bframe reference mode.

This gives results with average bitrate of around 2M, so I am guessing that is the default bitrate setting for nvenc. Increasing `-b:v` increases average bitrate, but around 6.5M it stops. Even using `-b:v 50M` gives the same video bitrate. I have also tried setting `-cq 1` to force the best quality possible, but that actually decreases bitrate to around 4.5M. The only way I found to get the desired bitrate is using `-cq 1` and `-maxrate` set to a big value. This removes the restriction, and actually the `-b:v` option is no longer needed, it seems like it doesn't have any effect at all.

All of this behaviour seems very strange to me, with some hidden default values for bitrate and maxrate, so the question is where can I see these values? I tried using ffmpeg with `-loglevel debug` but didn't see these values getting passed, and the documentation I found says maxrate default in ffmpeg is 0 (what does this mean?).

Comment: Did you checkout https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/4fee63b241e0dd254436bf38df8b0635b2b666d8/libavcodec/nvenc_hevc.c#L202? There are some values, but I'm not sure how they are passed around.

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg.exe -h encoder=hevc_nvenc
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as I've written there is no information on these default values in ffmpeg documentation.